# How to gain experience if the entry level job requirement is "1 year relevant experience""?

Tags: job-search, entry-level

Many jobs cite requirement of at least 1 year experience for entry level jobs. How can a fresh graduate gain and satisfy this requirement ?

Comment: [Is it really this hard to get an entry-level software job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/97104/is-it-really-this-hard-to-get-an-entry-level-software-job) [How can I overcome “years of experience” requirements when applying to positions?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/how-can-i-overcome-years-of-experience-requirements-when-applying-to-positions)

Comment: You won't get any of the jobs you don't apply to. Unless you are applying, in which case never mind.

Comment: A job that requires 1 year experience is not an entry level job. Apply to jobs that don't require experience.

Comment: I think I've looked at a hundred of job postings and I've seen one that didn't require at least a year experience maybe 4 times.

Comment: It's like you're asking "how can I afford a house if the $500,000 houses cost a million dollars?" If they cost a million dollars, they're not $500,000 houses. If they need a year's experience, they're not entry-level jobs. See the two linked questions for help getting out of your situation, but understand **they are not entry level jobs** and entry level jobs do exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I overcome "years of experience" requirements when applying to positions?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/how-can-i-overcome-years-of-experience-requirements-when-applying-to-positions)

Answer (score 4):

They cite at least 1 year of experience, as a fresh graduate, this experience can be satisfied via industry internships/externships, or projects you've worked on in an extracurricular manner. Now if you've made the grave oversight of not having any experience during school, you might have to reevaluate your plan.

Answer (score -1):

I graduated with no domain experience, though I held a steady 40hr/wk job through college. I applied *those* skills that I acquired working elsewhere to an entry-level part-time technician job in my field, where I worked 20hrs there and 20hrs part-time at an unrelated job. I transitioned into a full-time position in a role that I wanted after about 6 months by demonstrating to the employer that was where I wanted my future effort going. I accomplished that by going above what they wanted out of the technician role and edging into the domain role where possible. This was also beneficial because I understood more than one role and could wear more than one hat if I needed to. My total time from graduation to full-time domain role was 9 months.

Note that it takes a lot of work and a lot of thought, and that the role may open up for you faster, it may open up for you slower. I do, however, believe it entirely possible to make ends meet by **coming in a bit lower than you think you should**. A general problem I identified is that you graduate, and you immediately see dollar signs and conduct your job search accordingly. This can be a bit unrealistic, and you'll feel it during the job interviews. Since I don't know your situation I can't comment further, though.

Make note that for some fields, such as clinical/medical, this is vastly harder due to licensing/certification/training requirements.

Answer (score -2):

Ignore the years of experience "requirement". Just apply.

The worst thing that can happen is that your application is rejected. Most requirements are merely a wishlist.

Comment: And be instantly discarded as not meeting the requirement...

Comment: without an explanation, this answer may become useless in case if someone else posts an opposite opinion. For example, if someone posts a claim like _"Don't ignore the years of experience "requirement". Dont't just apply."_, how would this answer help reader to pick of two opposing opinions? Consider [edit]ing it into a better shape, to meet [answer] guidelines

Comment: @gnat: the reader can consider the potential outcomes of following the advice.  The only outcome of "don't apply" is not getting the job.  The possible outcomes of "apply" are (a) getting the job and (b) not getting the job.  Apply is the better advice.

Comment: It may be better advice, but without an explanation it is not useful on Stack Exchange